# R aggregate over time series, missing dates for some groups

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a problem when I aggregate data over a date series and a group where some dates are missing in one but not all of the groups.

```
dates <- seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"), by=7, length.out=5)
dates.2 <- dates[-2]
all.dates <- c(dates, dates, dates.2, dates.2)
subgroups <- c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5), rep("c", 4), rep("d", 4))
groups <- c(rep("X", 10), rep("Y", 8))
set.seed(2)

  df.1 <- data.frame(Date = all.dates, 
  Group = groups, 
  Subgrp = subgroups,
  Cost = runif(18,100,200)
)
df.1

         Date Group Subgrp     Cost
1  2010-01-01     X      a 118.4882
2  2010-01-08     X      a 170.2374
3  2010-01-15     X      a 157.3326
4  2010-01-22     X      a 116.8052
5  2010-01-29     X      a 194.3839
6  2010-01-01     X      b 194.3475
7  2010-01-08     X      b 112.9159
8  2010-01-15     X      b 183.3449
9  2010-01-22     X      b 146.8019
10 2010-01-29     X      b 154.9984
11 2010-01-01     Y      c 155.2674
12 2010-01-15     Y      c 123.8895
13 2010-01-22     Y      c 176.0513
14 2010-01-29     Y      c 118.0820
15 2010-01-01     Y      d 140.5282
16 2010-01-15     Y      d 185.3548
17 2010-01-22     Y      d 197.6398
18 2010-01-29     Y      d 122.5825

> ag.1 <- aggregate(Cost ~ Group + Date, FUN=sum,  data=df.1)
> ag.1
  Group       Date     Cost
1     X 2010-01-01 312.8357
2     Y 2010-01-01 295.7956
3     X 2010-01-08 283.1533
4     X 2010-01-15 340.6775
5     Y 2010-01-15 309.2443
6     X 2010-01-22 263.6070
7     Y 2010-01-22 373.6912
8     X 2010-01-29 349.3823
9     Y 2010-01-29 240.6646
```

Group `Y` has no payment on `2010-01-08` but the `ag.1` object is silent on this date for group `Y`. I would like `ag.1` to have a row reflecting this:

```
> ag.1
      Group       Date     Cost
    1     X 2010-01-01 312.8357
    2     Y 2010-01-01 295.7956
    3     X 2010-01-08 283.1533
    3a    Y 2010-01-08   0.0000
    4     X 2010-01-15 340.6775
    5     Y 2010-01-15 309.2443
```

I tried `na.omit=na.pass` in the `aggregate` function but (1) I don't really know what this does and (2) it didn't change the output.

Suggestions that don't use `aggregate` are welcome, but would prefer to use base packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand.grid` can be used to fill in missing entries.

```
df.2 <- expand.grid(Date = unique(dates),Group = unique(groups))
df <- merge(df.1,df.2,all=TRUE)

aggregate(Cost ~ Group + Date, FUN=sum,  data=df, na.action=na.pass)
```

EDIT: With the OP's hint, I found the appropriate tweak to the `aggregate` call.

```
   Group       Date     Cost
1      X 2010-01-01 312.8357
2      Y 2010-01-01 295.7956
3      X 2010-01-08 283.1533
4      Y 2010-01-08       NA
5      X 2010-01-15 340.6775
6      Y 2010-01-15 309.2443
7      X 2010-01-22 263.6070
8      Y 2010-01-22 373.6912
9      X 2010-01-29 349.3823
10     Y 2010-01-29 240.6646
```

Comment: I'd bet a good choice of `na.omit` would work with the formula syntax of aggregate.

Answer (score 1):

1) As long as for any date there is at least one group that has that date then this does it:

```
> as.data.frame(xtabs(Cost ~ Date + Group, df.1), responseName = "Cost")
         Date Group     Cost
1  2010-01-01     X 312.8357
2  2010-01-08     X 283.1533
3  2010-01-15     X 340.6775
4  2010-01-22     X 263.6070
5  2010-01-29     X 349.3823
6  2010-01-01     Y 295.7956
7  2010-01-08     Y   0.0000
8  2010-01-15     Y 309.2443
9  2010-01-22     Y 373.6912
10 2010-01-29     Y 240.6646
```

In fact the `xtabs` part of the above may be all you need if this layout is ok:

```
> xtabs(Cost ~ Date + Group, df.1)
            Group
Date                X        Y
  2010-01-01 312.8357 295.7956
  2010-01-08 283.1533   0.0000
  2010-01-15 340.6775 309.2443
  2010-01-22 263.6070 373.6912
  2010-01-29 349.3823 240.6646
```

2) If there are Dates for which no group has an entry then convert the Dates to a factor with the non-appearing dates included in the levels:

```
> # define levels to be all weeks between minimum date and 2010-02-05
> levs <- as.character(seq(min(df.1$Date), as.Date("2010-02-05"), by = 7))
> df.2 <- transform(df.1, Date = factor(Date, sort(unique(levs))))
>
> # now repeat using df.2
> as.data.frame(xtabs(Cost ~ Date + Group, df.2), responseName = "Cost")
         Date Group     Cost
1  2010-01-01     X 312.8357
2  2010-01-08     X 283.1533
3  2010-01-15     X 340.6775
4  2010-01-22     X 263.6070
5  2010-01-29     X 349.3823
6  2010-02-05     X   0.0000
7  2010-01-01     Y 295.7956
8  2010-01-08     Y   0.0000
9  2010-01-15     Y 309.2443
10 2010-01-22     Y 373.6912
11 2010-01-29     Y 240.6646
12 2010-02-05     Y   0.0000

> xtabs(Cost ~ Date + Group, df.2)
            Group
Date                X        Y
  2010-01-01 312.8357 295.7956
  2010-01-08 283.1533   0.0000
  2010-01-15 340.6775 309.2443
  2010-01-22 263.6070 373.6912
  2010-01-29 349.3823 240.6646
  2010-02-05   0.0000   0.0000
```